# Remove Windows 10 from dual boot with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, dualboot

[image: Gparted snap]

This is my hard disk snap in ubuntu Gparted application. I want to remove Windows 10. I had ubuntu installed after windows. 
My aim is to have my Linux files (sda6) and New volume(D drive) sda5 intact and format as much as possible from the rest of the disk and have a merged partition out of currently(sda1-sda4). I am bothered because of the EFI partition. Should I not remove that too? I have future plans to install parrot OS as my 2nd OS in my system alongside ubuntu.

For now, my plan is to have three parts only

```
sda1=rest(ext4)
sda5=new volume
sda6=ubuntu
```

So that I can migrate my data from sda5 to sda1, format sda5 as ext4 and copy back the data from sda1. And later I want to upgrade to

```
sda11=parrot
sda12=new volume 2(ext4)
sda5=new volume
sda6=ubuntu
```

I am confused about how to do it from my current system state. I want a riskless path to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The only risk-less way would be if you have a full backup that you have tested to work. Working with boot partitions is inherently risky.

One important thing to establish next is whether ubuntu is using efi.

Please share your /etc/fstab

And run this command as well:

[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"

I'll then update my answer according to what the next steps are for you.

Comment: Yes, my ubuntu is using efi.

cat /etc/fstab
`UUID=7ea08687-949b-4903-871e-a546c1ea6219 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1`
`UUID=B837-7943  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0`

Also, 
`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD"` gave me EFI boot on HDD **